Why CAN my subnet talk to my primary network when I don't want it to?
I have three networks:
Primary (192.168.1.x)
Secondary (192.168.2.x)
Tertiary (192.168.3.x)
All subnet masks are 255.255.255.0
Primary is my home network.  WAN of that router is plugged into my cable modem.
Secondary is my IOT network.  WAN of that router is plugged into LAN of primary.
Tertiary is my PPPOE camera network.  WAN of that router is plugged into LAN of primary.
My goal is for both subnets to be able to access the internet, but not each other or anything on my Primary home network.
My problem is that when I connect directly to either subnet's network (via phone, laptop) I can access devices on that network and my primary network.
All routers are ASUS RT-AX92U.
I have one static route to the tertiary network to allow me to VPN into my NVR instead of using the manufacturer's servers when I am away from home.
I swear at one point this all worked properly before...example: I couldn't access my NVR while on mobile data when I turned off the P2P until I learned what static routes are and how to use them (at a very basic level, mind you).
I absolutely assume this is something I have configured wrong.  I just don't have a clue as to what.  Or I completely misunderstand subnets.  Very possible.
I have even disabled all static routing on all routers, rebooted everything...and now I can't access the NVR from outside that network anymore (as expected).  But that NVR network (192.168.3.x) can still access the primary.
Also, with all static routes turned off, I can't access Tertiary from Secondary or vice versa...but both of those can access the primary.
Ideas?
Snarky remarks with intelligent recommendations?
All would be appreciated.

This primary network is the WAN of the secondary router and the tertiary router. Without any special setup, it's only natural that hosts in their LANs can access (unicast to) hosts in the primary network.

If you're talking about WAN interfaces for routers for the 2nd and 3rd networks I suspect you're also doing NAT rather than just routing. Inherently a device on these subsidiary networks will be able to reach anything their routers' WAN port can reach, which includes your primary network. You would be better using a single router that has connections for 1st, 2nd, 3rd networks and isolate them appropriately. My Draytek Vigor does this, for example, allowing 1-2 and 1-3 but none of 2-1, 3-1, 2-3, 3-2.

Hmm.  Okay then.  In that case it sounds like I should make the Primary router the IOT network and the secondary my secured home network.  That makes sense and is an easy fix.  Thank you Tom.  Chris, I will also look into your solution.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think we're looking at a misconception of how IP networking works. It's important to remember that networking is about connectivity. Letting devices talk to each other is the goal of networking. Connecting multiple sub-networks together into a larger inter-network is intended to allow all the devices on all those sub-networks to talk to all the others. In general, if you don't want two internetworked devices (or whole subnetworks) talking to each other, you have to take additional steps to break that connectivity, such as setting up firewall rules or tunneling.
I think you are so used to having home gateway routers that do NAT gatewaying on top of routing, that you're accustomed to how NAT breaks connectivity in one direction (stuff on the WAN side can't initiate connections to stuff on the LAN side without setting up something like port forwarding), and now you're accidentally expecting NAT to break connectivity in the other direction as well. But NAT doesn't break connectivity in that direction. At most it gets in the way of local-multicast-based service discovery protocols, but it doesn't break basic IP connectivity in that direction.

Spiff, you are absolutely correct it is misconception on my part.  I am reasonably smart in many things, but networking is not one of them.  Thank you for broadening my understanding.

Very often (when it is stateful; if not in most cases) NAT doesn't break connectivity in the other direction other. It's just that without having specific route(s) in the "upper" LAN hosts / router, traffics from them that are supposedly for the "lower" LAN hosts would never be routed to the right place, and the "lower" routers often have stateful firewall that forbid connection that are initiated from their WAN side, even if the necessary routes are in place.

What if you create a 4th subnet with a small mask, like 255.255.255.248, call it 192.168.0.0, and have that connected to the ISP WAN. Connect the "WAN" side, or gateway of each of the other three networks to that. Then set up so the Secondary and Tertiary cannot connect to the Primary's gateway by not routing it to do so. So something like this...
                                                                     |=== 192.168.0.2 > {Router} < 192.168.1.1/24 (GW) Primary >
                                                                     |
ISP WAN <= ISP IP Address (external) > {Router} < 192.168.0.1/29 <===-=== 192.168.0.3 > {Router} < 192.168.2.1/24 (GW) Secondary >
                                                                     |
                                                                     |=== 192.168.0.4 > {Router} < 192.168.3.1/24 (GW) Tertiary >

Route Primary, secondary and tertiary to get to 192.168.0.1 and then to ISP IP address, but not to the other networks.
